# Moving a json file from databricks to blob storage

Tags: json, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I have created a mount in databricks which connects to my blob storage and I am able to read files from blob to databricks using a notebook.

I then transposed a .txt to json format using pyspark and now I would like to load it back to the blob storage. Does anyone know how I would do that?

Here are a few things I have tried:

`my_json.write.option("header", "true").json("mnt/my_mount/file_name.json")`

`write.json(my_json, mnt/my_mount)`

Neither work. I can put load a csv file from databricks to blob using:

`my_data_frame.write.option("header", "true").csv("mnt/my_mount_name/file name.csv")`

This works fine but I can't find a solution for moving a json.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I am new to pySpark but this is what I have done.*

This is what I did after referencing the docs [pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.json](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.json)

```py
# JSON
my_dataframe.write.json("/mnt/my_mount/my_json_file_name.json")

# For a single JSON file
my_dataframe.repartition(1).write.json("/mnt/my_mount/my_json_file_name.json")

# Parquet
my_dataframe.write.mode("Overwrite").partitionBy("myCol").parquet("/mnt/my_mount/my_parquet_file_name.parquet")
```